# cmake find_library returns NOT_FOUND

Tags: cmake

I have placed a set of library files at a hard coded directory and am directing find_library to find those library files and it always fails.

OS: Mac OSX 10.9.5

hard coded directory where I have placed my library files = `/Users/kgeorge/Documents/projects/opencv-for-android/opencv/3rdparty/ffmpeg/lib`

```
ls /Users/kgeorge/Documents/projects/opencv-for-android/opencv/3rdparty/ffmpeg/lib
```

gives

```
libavcodec.a    libavformat.a   libswresample.a pkgconfig
libavfilter.a   libavutil.a libswscale.a
```

My cmake fragment has the following code sequence

```
set(FFMPEG_LIB_DIR   "/Users/kgeorge/Documents/projects/opencv-for-android/opencv/3rdparty/ffmpeg/lib")
FIND_LIBRARY(FFMPEG_CODEC_LIB avcodec PATHS ${FFMPEG_LIB_DIR} NO_DEFAULT_PATH )
message("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" ${FFMPEG_CODEC_LIB})
```

**After removing all the cmake caches** (I remove the build directory) , I run cmake afresh, and I am getting the following response.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@FFMPEG_CODEC_LIB-NOTFOUND
```

I tried various versions of this, but so far of no avail.

```
FIND_LIBRARY(FFMPEG_CODEC_LIB avcodec PATHS ${FFMPEG_LIB_DIR}  )
FIND_LIBRARY(FFMPEG_CODEC_LIB libavcodec.a PATHS ${FFMPEG_LIB_DIR} NO_DEFAULT_PATH )
FIND_LIBRARY(FFMPEG_CODEC_LIB avcodec HINTS ${FFMPEG_LIB_DIR} NO_DEFAULT_PATH )
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to find libraries for Android on OSX. Did you set up cross compilation in CMake? Otherwise, that won't works...

Comment: Thanks for the response. These libraries were separately pre-built for the same arm architecture (viz  armv7-a), that I am compiling opencv for. But I doubt that concern is relevant to  the functioning of  find_library.